# simple command line Ruby application

Tags: ruby, command-line, ubuntu-14.04, executable

I have been asked to develop a simple command line Ruby application that retrieves results from an external API with a specified search query. I have created a script to do that and made it executable using `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`. My script name is **sampleapp.rb**. So I can run it from console as

```
$> ./sampleapp some_argument
```

That is only when I am inside the file directory.

In the example given to me, the script/app was supposed to run like this:

```
$> sampleapp some_argument
```

I did a lot of research but couldn't find a way to achieve this. Please guide me here.

Also, how can I make this sampleapp global so it can be called from anywhere.

Update:

**sampleapp.rb**

```
require 'net/https'
require 'openssl'
require 'json'
require 'uri'
require 'cgi'

module Someapp

  class SampleApp

    def search(query ="")
     ...some code here ...
    end

  if ARGV.size == 0 || ARGV[0].strip == ""
    puts "Please provide search query as an argument"
  else
    query = ARGV[0].strip
    SampleApp.new.search(query)
  end
end
```

Comment: Assuming some *nix variant, you'd need to make it executable (```chmod +x sampleapp```), and have it live in a directory that's in your (or more generally the caller's) ```$PATH```. As the already given answer suggests, one way to do this is to put it in ```/usr/local/bin```.

Comment: @DerrellDurrett I doubt you understand how ruby classpath works.

Comment: There are great libraries for this take a look at [`thor`](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor) or [`slop`](https://github.com/leejarvis/slop) they can make this task much easier and far more friendly when scope creep causes "Simple" to all of sudden change to "Complex".

Comment: This is an OS question, not Ruby. The file has to be in the executable path to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this script does not depend on any 3rd party library (what is unlikely) and runs smoothly with system `ruby`, the easiest way would be to copy it to `/usr/local/bin` folder:

```
sudo cp ./sampleapp /usr/local/bin/
```

If it depends on other libraries, the preferred way would be to build a gem out of it, and install it with system `ruby`. There are many tutorials on how to produce a `gem`, [the canonical one is likely this](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/).

Comment: I have created a gem too but I'm not sure how I'd run it as a console application. I'm updating the question with dependencies.

Comment: Read how to create executables and ship them with a gem in the article I linked (section “ADDING AN EXECUTABLE”.)

Comment: The question remains. How and what should I ship so that it runs on another machine as stated in the question?

Comment: A gem. When the gem will be installed on another machine, dependencies will be resolved and the executables will be automatically made available for the execution. **Please read the article I linked, instead of asking questions, that are perfectly answered there.**

Comment: There is no need to copy the file to a directory, just make sure the directory is in the PATH.

Comment: Thank you @mudasobwa. For some reason, it worked only when the folder was copied to /usr/local/bin. I do want to create a gem for such a small test app so I guess I'll ask them to follow the same steps to make the script executable.

Comment: Welcome. You might also want to just tune the `$PATH` variable as suggested by @theTinMan above.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have any effect. I added the directory path to /usr/local/bin but then removed it to understand what worked. It seems just by copying the folder as you suggested, it is working as expected. By folder I mean a script without any extension containing ruby code. Now when I type, > sampleapp some_param, it works fine.

Comment: You shouldn't copy a _folder_ to /usr/local/bin, only individual files, or create a symlink in /usr/local/bin to the file in its original location. "added the directory path to /usr/local/bin" doesn't make sense. Did you add `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH because it didn't exist already? A folder isn't a script, just as a folder isn't a file. Whether a file has an extension or not doesn't change it into a folder, it remains a file.